# Prove that this language is undecidable

Tags: turing-machines, formal-languages

Is the following language *L* undecidable?

> *L* = {*M* | *M* is a Turing machine description and there exists an input *x* of length *k* such that *M* halts after at most *k* steps}

I think it is but I couldn't prove it. I tried to think of a reduction from the halting problem.

Comment: k is a fixed constant here, right?

Comment: no. If k is fixed then it is decidable I think

Comment: Forgive me if this is a naive approach, but-- if I want to know whether a machine X halts (without input), can I enclose it in another machine Y which will *ignore* input? That is, if you run Y with any input, Y will just run X, perhaps with a fixed number of steps of overhead? If so then X halts iff Y is a member of L, so L is undecidable. Is this a workable approach? Or must Y *erase* the input or something?

Comment: You can do that. Or Y can run on X if its input is X and loop otherwise. the problem here is that X is unknown.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Review: An instance of the halting problem asks whether Turning machine *N* halts on input *y*. The problem is known to be undecidable (but semidecidable).

**Your language *L* is indeed undecidable**. This can be shown by reducing the halting problem to *L*:

1. For the halting problem instance (*N*, *y*), create a new machine *M* for the *L* problem.
2. On input *x*, *M* simulates (*N*, *y*) for length(*x*) steps.
3. If the simulation halted within that number of steps, then *M* halts. Otherwise, *M* deliberately goes into an infinite loop.

This reduction is valid because:

- If (*N*, *y*) does halt eventually in *k* steps, then *M* will halt for all inputs of length *k* or greater, thus *M* is in *L*.
- Otherwise (*N*, *y*) does not halt, then *M* will not halt for any input string no matter how long it is, thus *M* is not in *L*.

Finally, the halting problem is undecidable, therefore *L* is undecidable.